C++ CURL POST request with headers & data
I am new to C++ and I am trying to make a POST request API call. If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. The function in question is "tokens".
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 1000

using namespace std;

const BIO_METHOD* BIO_f_base64(void);

string tokens(string accessCode, string base64Encode) {
    
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {

        string json = "{'grant_type':'authorization_code','code':'" + accessCode + "','redirect_uri':'https://127.0.0.1'}";

        struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;

        string authorization("Authorization: Basic ");
        string payload = authorization + base64Encode;
        const char* cstr = payload.c_str();

        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, cstr);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.schwabapi.com/v1/oauth/token");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, 12L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);

    }
    
    return readBuffer;

}

The API call seems to go through but I get this response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Unauthorized"}

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are making quite a few mistakes.
You are leaking 2 CURL objects, because you are calling curl_easy_init() twice, and not calling curl_easy_cleanup() at all.
application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the wrong media type to use for a JSON payload. Use application/json instead.
Your JSON data is longer than 12 characters. Use json.size() for the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE value.
For CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, you can't pass a string object to curl_easy_setopt(). Use json.c_str() instead.
Try this:
string tokens(string accessCode, string base64Encode) {
    
    string readBuffer;

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {

        string json = "{'grant_type':'authorization_code','code':'" + accessCode + "','redirect_uri':'https://127.0.0.1'}";
        string authorization = "Authorization: Basic " + base64Encode;

        curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, authorization.c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.schwabapi.com/v1/oauth/token");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, static_cast<long>(json.size()));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    
    return readBuffer;
}


That being said, consider using cURLpp, which is a C++ wrapper for libcurl, eg:
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <curlpp/CURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

std::string tokens(std::string accessCode, std::string base64Encode) {
    cURLpp::Easy request;
    using namespace curlpp::options;

    std::string json = "{'grant_type':'authorization_code','code':'" + accessCode + "','redirect_uri':'https://127.0.0.1'}";

    std::list<std::string> headers;
    headers.push_back("Authorization: Basic " + base64Encode);
    headers.push_back("Content-Type: application/json");
    request.setOpt<HttpHeader>(headers);

    request.setOpt<Url>("https://api.schwabapi.com/v1/oauth/token");

    request.setOpt<PostFieldSize>(static_cast<long>(json.size()));
    request.setOpt<PostFields>(json);

    std::ostringstream os;

    request.setOpt<WriteStream>(&os);
    request.perform();
    // or simply:
    // os << request;

    return os.str();
}


the Oauth 2 documentation is listed on Schwab's website at this URL: https://developer.schwab.com/user-guides/get-started/authenticate-with-oauth
the documetation is on page 29 on the documentation: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#appendix-A.10
 Host: server.example.com
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
 &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb


thank you for the corrections. I have tried using the data string as prescribed in the documentation. I will add my base64 encryption function in the original post.

That example is not posting JSON in the request body, so application/x-www-form-urlencoded is appropriate in that case

thats what I originally tried an I had the same error. I am still getting the same error with string json = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + accessCode + "&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1"; after applying your other corrections. any suggestions?

If you are doing your own base64 encoding (and BTW, base64 is not encryption), then you should consider not using it at all. Curl has CURLOPT_USERPWD and CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER options.
